# Building texlive from scratch on a server

Tags: pdftex, texlive

several times a week I need to compile a pdf file with varying content. Therefore, I wrote a bash script which reads this content from a text file, parses it into a .tex file then runs `pdflatex` on this file. To be more independent of my computer, I tried an online solution. I managed to talk our company system administrator at work to install the texlive environment at the server. So on my own company webspace, I added an HTML file and a PHP script. Now data is entered into an HTML text box, the PHP script writes it into a local file, calls my former script and lets me download the compiled pdf file. Everything is pretty smooth so far.

But since I also use this script for my leisure time, I don't feel comfortable using my work resources for that, even though it is my private web space. Hence, I moved to a webhosting server at [www.hetzner.de](http://www.hetzner.de) where the admins told me that LaTeX is not installed but can be compiled from source. I've read several guides but still don't have a clue on how to do it. I would not need the full texlive environment, but just the pdftex compiler and a few tex packages (such as babel, fontenc, inputenc and geometry). Could anyone guide me or recommend an easy explanation on how to build texlive from source?

Thank you in advance

Comment: odd that you need to compile, if you can upload files there you could just upload the normal texlive installer, or if docker is available run a docker texlive image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I followed the hint of [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) and downloaded the `install-tl-unx.tar.gz` from [here](https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html). I then transferred the file via FTP onto the server in a texlive directory which I created before, unpacked it and ran the [quick installation process](https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) which is basically just `perl install-tl`. As I had no rights to write onto `/usr/local/texlive/2020`, I had to change the installation path and installed everything into ~/texlive . The installation took a while but went smoothly. The only minor inconvenience is inherently connected to the installation process: `pdflatex` now isn't a globally known program and hence, if I want to compile `foo.tex`, I have to call it by `~/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex foo.tex` but since this is just done one time in the script and I'm not touching that too often, I can live with that.

Sorry if that was too much detail but maybe it will help someone in the future, who wants to do a similar thing.